# jQuery insertBefore() and parentNode appears flaky

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a set of div's that are in a jQuery nested collapsible set which require a bit if playing around to get them to work.  I have gotten these to work, but now want to add the ability to shift listed items up on the page by request when clicking on an up arrow i have placed. I have the javascript written that works (sort of) to move the div's as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.upItem').click(function(event) {
            if($(this.parentNode.parentNode).index() === 0) {
                alert($(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr('name') + ' is currently at the top');
            } else {
                $(this.parentNode.parentNode).insertBefore(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling);
                alert($(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr('name') + ' moved Up');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

The parent node chunks are to get the right elements to move, and they do appear to move just fine eventually.

I am using PHP generated HTML similar to the following:

```
<div name="H4Order_1" class="h4Holder">
<h4 id="L2_item_29" class="collapsible collapse-open"><span></span>SuperBowl</h4>
<div class="container2" style="display: block;">
    <div name="H5Order_1" class="h5Holder">
        <span class="buttonHolder">
            <span class="upItem">▲</span>
        </span>
        <h5>Item 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div name="H5Order_2" class="h5Holder">
        <span class="buttonHolder">
            <span class="upItem">▲</span>
        </span>
        <h5>Item 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div name="H5Order_3" class="h5Holder">
        <span class="buttonHolder">
            <span class="upItem">▲</span>
        </span>
        <h5>Item 3</h5>
    </div>
    <div name="H5Order_4" class="h5Holder">
        <span class="buttonHolder">
            <span class="upItem">▲</span>
        </span>
        <h5>Item 4</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

the issue I am having is that when i click on the elements with the class .upItem, the script triggers and i can see the alerts when the item is at the top as well as when it is "moved", but often the element does not actually move.  I will see the alert that it has been moved, but it does not move up as expected. On the next click it will move. Sometimes after clicking a bit here and there all the elements start moving as expected with one click each but this is only after having messed around with lots of clicks on multiple items.

Is there any way i can troubleshoot to find out why sometimes it takes 2 clicks to get am item to actually move?

***Per request here is the jfiddle:***

http://jsfiddle.net/jwnqh/

Comment: it will be better if we can see this happening.. can u create a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Use the DOM inspector and Javascript debugger in your browser to troubleshoot this.

Comment: The reason for the problem is that `.previousSibling` returns a text node containing whitespace. You need to use `.previousElementSibling`, but the jQuery codes in the answers are clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to insert the node before `previousSibling` whereas [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.previousElementSibling) is what you wanted. This is because there's a text node between the two parent containers.

Of course, this particular property is relatively new and won't work for older browsers (IE < 9) unless you have a workaround.

This would be a far more straightforward way to move items up the sibling chain:

```
$('.upItem').click(function(event) {
  //var $parent = $(this).closest('.h5Holder');
  var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();

  if ($parent.index() === 0) {
    alert($parent.attr('name') + ' is currently at the top');
  } else {
    $parent.prev().before($parent);
    alert($parent.attr('name') + ' moved Up');
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/unanum/1/)

Here, `.prev().before()` makes sure that you're inserting before the previous element instead of the previous node.

It also caches the parent container of the anchor, making the code a lot easier to follow.

Comment: I will adjust and see if this works for me .. i'll let you know shortly.

Comment: looks like that works, though i have to adjust as i need to account for nested format (i.e. i have H1, H2, H3, H4 and H5,). is there a way to have the .closest() using a common class for all levels? or will I need to create a function for each level? .h1Holder, .h2Holder, etc?

Comment: @Silvertiger If the container element is always separated by two levels, instead of `.closest()` you can just use `.parent().parent()` of course :)

Comment: @jack isn't that essentially what i was doing with parentNode.parentNode? or is that different?

Comment: @Silvertiger That's exactly the same as `parentNode.parentNode` :)

Comment: @jack excellent .. works like a charm - I guess the issue was the prev() vs. insertBefore(0). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dkq7y/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.upItem').click(function(event) {
        var div = $(this).closest('div.h5Holder');
            if(div.index() === 0) {
                alert(div.attr('name') + ' is currently at the top');
                return;
            }
         div.insertBefore(div.prev());
        alert(div.attr('name') + ' moved Up');
        }
    );
});
```

Your  `$(this.parentNode.parentNode).insertBefore(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling);` is the culprit as `this.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling` gives a textnode (whitespace) instead of actual element that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `previousElementSibling` to skip over textnodes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.upItem').click(function (event) {
        if ($(this.parentNode.parentNode).index() === 0) {
            alert($(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr('name') + ' is currently at the top');
        } else {
            $(this.parentNode.parentNode).insertBefore(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling);
            alert($(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr('name') + ' moved Up');
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Dkq7y/4/)